# why i get error at opticFlow = opticalFlowHS; matlab2015a

Tags: matlab, opticalflow

i don't know why i get error at opticFlow = opticalFlowHS; in matlab2015a

Undefined function or variable 'opticalFlowHS'.

Error in test (line 3)
opticFlow = opticalFlowHS;

these toolboxes already installed.

MATLAB                                                Version 8.5        (R2015a)
Image Acquisition Toolbox                             Version 4.9        (R2015a)
Image Processing Toolbox                              Version 9.2        (R2015a)

Comment: i'm trying to run these codes:

vidReader = VideoReader('fileVDINfild.avi');

opticFlow = opticalFlowHS;

while hasFrame(vidReader)
    frameRGB = readFrame(vidReader);
    frameGray = rgb2gray(frameRGB);

    flow = estimateFlow(opticFlow,frameGray);


    imshow(frameRGB)

Answer (score 1):

To be able to use opticalFlowHS you need to have Computer Vision System Toolbox installed.